# Simplest way to put text on drawable programmatically

Tags: android, drawing, drawable

I have this icon: [image: icon]

I am going to work with it as `drawable`.

```
Drawable myIcon = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.icon );
```

I need programmaticaly put some text on it (file extension).

This is my desired result: [image: desired result].

I can't make several static icons because I can receive arbitrary file extension

Comment: it's simple, take an `ImageView` and `TextView` inside `RelativeLayout`. set TextView's gravity to center of Layout.

Comment: this and other answers which use  RelativeLayout are not suitable for me because I need to receive Drawable. And I don't want to convert Layout to Bitmap/Drawable

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
public BitmapDrawable writeOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text){

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

        Paint paint = new Paint(); 
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);  
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
        paint.setTextSize(20); 

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
        canvas.drawText(text, 0, bm.getHeight()/2, paint);

        return new BitmapDrawable(bm);
    }
```

**Use this method.will help you.**

Comment: nice solution 

Comment: Somehow this drastically reduces the size of the drawable. I've tried placing the icon in drawable-nodpi etc, same issue :(

Comment: fixed by 
        return new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bm);

:)

Comment: Got "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap.copy(android.graphics.Bitmap$Config, boolean)' on a null object reference."  copy can return "null." Had to check "bm" for null before using.  Not sure why as resource is valid - still researching.

Answer (score 2):

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/folder"
                    android:src="@drawable/image_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


                 <TextView

                    android:textColor="@color/green"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:id="@+id/text"
                    android:text="10"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to print somewhere this image and you simply have to display it on the screen, probably the easiest way is to print the `text` on the center of the `img`.

You can do it by using a `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout> // Only works inside a RelativeLayout
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/myImageSouce" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/myImageText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/myImage"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myImage"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myImage"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myImage"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

This is probably the easiest solution and it will align the text at the center of the image, based on img sizes.